# How to use setInterval to trigger a function so that I can stop it at some point?

Tags: javascript

So from what I have understood, setInterval() is used to call a function on repeat on regular intervals.
So basically it is a loop that executes a function forever periodically.

I am confused as to if I had to stop this execution at one point what would be the way to do it

for eg I am trying to print the message "hey" 3 times after 1 second each, but somehow it is printing it 3 times every second and is going on forever.
What can I do to stop it after a set number of times.

This is the code that I've been trying

```
var i = 3;
function message() {
  console.log("hey");
}

while(i > 0) {
  setInterval(message, 1000);
  i = i - 1;
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` is not intended to ran `x` times, but rather to run every `x` ms. If you want it to run `x` times, see @eis 's answer how it can be accomplished using `setTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is executing the setInterval thrice in the while loop, which is not needed.
Actually, setInterval does not work as a function call but actually registers a function to be called at some interval.
The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` i.e it is deregistered or the process is killed.

It should work like this

```
var i = 3;
var interval = setInterval(message, 1000);

function message() {
    if (i === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    console.log("hey");
    i = i - 1;
}
```

Comment: `if (i-- === 0)` or even just `if (!i--)`

Answer (score 2):

To clear a setInterval, use global `clearInterval` method.
Example:

```
var timerId = setInterval(func, 500);
.... some code here....
clearInterval(timerId);
```

Comment: With the structure shown here, the interval will be cleared before it has ever run.

Comment: This was just to keep the simplicity. Otherwise the place of `clearInterval` depends on use case. ... some code here... is not here to indicate that some code is running in sequence, it is there just to indicate that there you got some code and when you want to clear interval, this is what you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do to stop it after a set number of times.

usually you don't use setInterval() for this, you use setTimeout().

Something like

```
var counter = 0;

function message() {
  console.log("hey");

  // we trigger the function again after a second, if not already done 3 times
  if (counter < 3) {
    setTimeout(message, 1000);
  }
  counter++;
}

// initial startup after a second, could be faster too
setTimeout(message, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval` function calls the function indefinitely, whereas `setTimeout` calls the function once only.

Simply use `clearInterval` once the count runs out.

```
var i = 3;

function message(){
  console.log("hey");
  if (--i < 0) {
    clearInterval(tmr);
  }
}

var tmr = setInterval(message, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign that setInterval to a javascript variable to name it what for this setInterval, like this

```
var messageLog = setInterval(message, 1000);
```

After, in setInterval message function add this condition to clear the inverval whenever you want to clear.

```
function message(){
  if(i>3) {
     clearInterval(messageLog);     // clearInterval is a javascript function to clear Intervals. 
     return null;
  }
   console.log("hey");
}
```

Comment: You need to increment `i`

Comment: @OrangeDog no need, In his code he will increment or decrement inside the while loop, that's why am not adding inside message function.

Comment: That's completely wrong. There shouldn't even be a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the timer when creating and clear it if needed.

```
var i=3;
var timer = setInterval(message,1000);
function message(){
  console.log("hey");
  i—-;
  if(i==0)
      clearInterval(timer)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a beginner here too,look for clearInterval method ...